# c++ mfc gdi double buffer costs too large memory

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I'm doing a vector graphic app.
mfc scrollview
it can zoom in/out so I may SetScrollSizes to max 10000.
everything is smooth but the graph flicker.
So I use double buffer(buffer dc selectobject a  buffer bitmap).

CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, 10000, 10000) (because the canvas can reach max 10000*10000)

the result is not smooth at all.
How can I avoid the large memory use of the buffer bitmap?
Thank you

How can I avoid the large memory use of the buffer bitmap?
or is it another way to ensure smoothness?
Thank you

Comment: The nice thing about vector graphics, is that everything can be calculated and nothing has to be pre-rendered. That means you don't really need a very large bitmap to pre-render anything, instead calculate everything drawn inside the smaller window.

Comment: because I need to scroll the window I have to render all the graphics on DC. (no smoothness problem in pDC of CScrollView) the problem lies in the memory bitmap buffer

Comment: by the way I render text and bezier polys.

Comment: You can optimize your application by painting only the part of the scroll-view that is visible. And as mentioned above, you should NOT pre-render it, as it can produce different results for each zoom-level. Eg if you render the bitmap for 100% zoom, then how will you zoom-in? By using GDI scaling/stretching? You're going to get pixelated or blurred graphics, while vector graphics can produce very smooth ones. So you don't need that huge bitmap, just make it as large as your screen, maybe you can add a few pixels around it if you have problems drawing the areas close to the border.

Comment: Consider using the function ScrollWindow(), which avoids re-drawing the part of view, which remains visible. This part will scroll completely flicker-free.